# How do you set Toggle UI interactable size manually in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, size, toggle

I'm trying to make a toggle UI like the one on this youtube([https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQTnB71NUAw&ab_channel=MaxShakurov"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQTnB71NUAw&ab_channel=MaxShakurov%22)).

This example uses a button UI to make this happen. But I'm trying to make it with a toggle UI that Unity provides.

But here is the problem that I faced.

**Issue:** There is a big difference in the interactable box size of what I expected.

Below is an example to make it easy to reproduce.
My Unity version: 2018.4.23f1

1. I created a new project.
2. I added a default toggle UI
3. ---> There is a big difference between my expectation of interactable box size and the actual one.

[image]

My initial expectation was to make toggle UI to be able to interact with the size of its' target graphic.

How can you make a toggle UI to be able to interact on only the size of a target graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction space is expanded to any child object having a graphic element (`Image`, `Text`, etc) with `Raycast Target` enabled.

All you have to do is

1. Go to the `Label` object in the Hierarchy
2. Go to the `Text` component in the Inspector
3. Disable the `Raycast Target` checkbox

   [image]

As a result you should now have only the checkbox itself interactive

[image]

Comment: Oh... Thank you so much. I only disabled the background image. Great help!